# How to get a complete list of blocks that are active content on current page?

Tags: 7, blocks, advertising

I'm trying to get a full list of blocks that are active content on the current page. Preferably it would include details of what type of content is displayed in the block.

I need this information to display ads in the blocks. The ads need to be loaded through the javascript snippet, that I can place in the header (through drupal_add_js). But first I need to know if the block that contains the ad is active and that's why I need this list of blocks.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: do you want to get the id of the block to use it in the js?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction to get the details of block for current page

- In this [template_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) function You can get a variable in that u have all region and it's block array
- Using the above function we can get all the information of blocks note(if u want to see know the regions list see this function [system_region_list](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_region_list/7)

Answer (score 0):

If you want dump out all the blocks on page then do the following:

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
   var_dump($vars);
   // dsm(); // If Devel module installed.
}
```

You do this in your themes template file, replacing THEME (above) with your theme.